# Unhandled Exception: Type ContentPage.Content not found in in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

Trying to figure out Xamaring and VS by playing around with it and I've had an issue with MasterDetailPages for a couple of days.

Process

- Went from a blank file and turned the MainPage.xaml into the
  MasterDetailPage
- added a content page into MasterDetailPage.Master
  and a content page into MasterDetailPage.Detail
- Added a stack layout and a label into both of their ContentPage.Content and ran the project fine.

Thought I'd try out the next step and add a new xaml file as a reference ContentPage, but just with the .Master first. Code went from

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Master Page" Padding="10">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                <Label Text="NavMenu Master Page"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master/>


//TO WHAT I HAVE BELOW THIS

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:NavMenu Title=NavMenu/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Ran the file and I got the error that is in the title. Tried to troubleshoot by rolling it back to the original conent and the error persisted. Created a new file, copied and pasted the code into the other file and it ran just fine.

I'm clueless to what the issued is and how I should go about fixing it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, since you said:  "Created a new file, copied and pasted the code into the other file and it ran just fine." Maybe something is broken with your old file, maybe you can share us to have a test.

Answer (score 0):

With your first code, it isn't necessary to put `ContentPage.Content` as it is implicit that the code is child from that element. Other than that, your code seems to be fine.

Comment: Which is why I'm clueless. It''s a bit redundant to have it there, but once the error occurs, it persists. I appreciate the response anyways.

Comment: Change it, clean your solution and rebuild. I had that problem a while ago;

Comment: Changed it, cleaned it, rebuilt it, the '.Droid.MainPage.xaml.g.cs' file throws an unhandled exception referencing 'ContentPage.Content' despite there note being a 'ContentPage.Content'  in MainPage.xaml.cs.